# How to open Emacs (Terminal) using key combinations?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

On Ubuntu, to open the Terminal, we press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>.

Do there exist key combinations to open Emacs Terminal (without GUI)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [define your own shortcut](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html) that executes the command `x-terminal-emulator -e emacs -nw`